# How to apply code on multiple files at once?

Tags: php

I couldn't find a solution to this. I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

I have 4 log files and I need to remove all log except last 10 lines.

I'm able to do it for 1 file but how to apply it on 4 files using once simple php code?

My current code:

```
<?php
$lines_array = file("log.txt");
    $lines = count($lines_array); 
    $new_output = "";

    for ($i=$lines - 10; $i < $lines; $i++) {
        $new_output .= $lines_array[$i];
        }

    $filename = "log.txt";
    file_put_contents($filename,$new_output);
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Make it a function that accepts file name as argument. Then call it for each of your logs

Comment: Thank you, please bear with me, should I put each file in a function? I was trying to use arrays but it's only giving me errors

Comment: added example with array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional programming to the rescue:

```
function rotate(string $filename)
{
    $lines_array = file($filename);
    $lines = count($lines_array); 
    $new_output = "";

    for ($i=$lines - 10; $i < $lines; $i++) {
        $new_output .= $lines_array[$i];
        }

    file_put_contents($filename,$new_output);
}

rotate('log1.txt');
rotate('someOtherLog.txt');
rotate('third/log/file.txt);
//etc.

// or,

$logs = [
    'log1.txt',
    'someOtherLog.txt',
    'third/log/file.txt'
];

foreach($logs as $file) {
    rotate($file);
}
```

This allows you to write the code for rotating your logs one time, which makes your code better by being DRY (Don’t Repeat Yourself)

Comment: thank you. I got this error: https://pastebin.pl/view/46135996

Comment: Oh, I just copied your code. Notice that I passed in `$fileName` but left your existing `$filename`.

Comment: Corrected my code to reflect your naming convention. I’m typing on a phone, so errors are quite possible ;)

Comment: Excellent solution. Clean and Smooth, thank you so much

Comment: You’re quite welcome

Answer (score 1):

List your logfiles in an array, and loop over it, rewriting the log files as you go:

```
$logs = [
    'log1.txt',
    'log2.txt',
    'log3.log'
];
foreach($logs as $log) {
    // Only do this if we read the file.
    if ($logData = file($log)) {
        // array_slice takes a portion of the array
        file_put_contents($log, array_slice($logData,-10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input, I wanted to try your code even that Tim provided me with the solution, but it's showing this error: https://pastebin.pl/view/9f0916b8

Comment: My mistake - I missed the filename parameter in `file_put_contents()`. Fixed now.

Comment: concise solution that handles file not found

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<?php 
$fp = fopen("log.txt","ab+");
$data = fread($fp,filesize("log.txt"));
$data_array = explode("\n",$data);


$new_data = array();

for($i = count($data_array) - 1; $i >= count($data_array) - 10;$i--)
{ 
    array_push($new_data , $data_array[$i]);
}
fclose($fp);


$new_data_array = array_reverse($new_data);

$data = implode("\n",$new_data_array);
$fp = fopen("log.txt","w");
fwrite($fp,$data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this will be applied on 1 file, right? what about 4 files? can you explain your code please

Comment: you can put there path in one array and do a for loop